# Templates in Rsyslog 8.17

Tags: rsyslog

Recently I patched my system and the installed rsyslog version changed from 8.10 to 8.17. Somehow this update broke all my templates. My custom properties aren't recognized anymore (For example Mark, Flag, Windowsize etc.). Here is an example:

```
template(name="FWToJSON-TCP" type="list") {
  constant(value="{")
  constant(value="\"TimeStamp\":\"") property(name="timereported"       dateFormat="rfc3339") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Mark\":\"") property(name="$!Mark" format="json")     constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"UrgentFlag\":\"") property(name="!UrgentFlag"  format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Flag\":\"") property(name="$!Flag" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"WindowSize\":\"") property(name="$!WindowSize" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"AckNumber\":\"") property(name="$!AckNumber" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"SequenceNumber\":\"") property(name="$!SequenceNumber" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"DestinationPort\":\"") property(name="$!DestinationPort" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"SourcePort\":\"") property(name="$!SourcePort" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Protocol\":\"") property(name="$!Protocol" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"FragmentFlag\":\"") property(name="$!FragmentFlag" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"ID\":\"") property(name="$!ID" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"TTL\":\"") property(name="$!TTL" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Precedence\":\"") property(name="$!Precedence" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"TypeOfService\":\"") property(name="$!TypeOfService" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Length\":\"") property(name="$!Length" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"DestinationIP\":\"") property(name="$!DestinationIP" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"SourceIP\":\"") property(name="!$SourceIP" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"OutputDevice\":\"") property(name="$!OutputDevice" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"InputDevice\":\"") property(name="$!InputDevice" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Prefix\":\"") property(name="$!Prefix" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Policy\":\"") property(name="$!Policy" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Chain\":\"") property(name="$!Chain" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"FW\":\"") property(name="$!FW" format="json") constant(value="\",")
  constant(value="\"Message\":\"") property(name="msg" format="json") constant(value="\"")
  constant(value="}")
}
```

The logs are normalized via the mmnormalize module and this still works as it seems. Does anyone know how to get these template working again?